Google Programmable Search Engine
I have a website with the following structure:
site.com/game-01
site.com/game-02
site.com/game-03

and so on...
There are additional sections for each such section:
site.com/game-01/news
site.com/game-01/forum
site.com/game-01/solution

And so on...
Would like to use Google's Programmable Search Engine and limit the search to the scope of the game on which the user is located.
Example: the user is on the page site.com/game-01/forum012/post08.html Only pages  of section site.com/game-01/ should be displayed in the search results
How to implement it?
The main question, how can I dynamically change the pages included in the search?
